# If three functions A, B and C are mutually orthogonal, is the inner product of all three functions equal to zero?

Tags: orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-polynomials

Let A, B and C be mutually orthogonal functions. If so, would the following equation hold true? Is there a theorem proving this?

$\int_a^{b}ABCdx = 0$

Comment: Are you supposing $A, B, C$ continuous?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes they are continuous

Comment: No, your integral is not "an inner product of all three functions". It is an inner product of $A$ and $BC$ (or of $B$ and $AC$, or $C$ and $AB$). But $BC$ does not necessarily share any orthogonality properties with $B$ or $C$. For example, take $A=\sin x$, $B=\cos x$, $C=\sin 2x$ on $[0,2\pi]$. These three functions are orthogonal, but $\int ABC\,\mathrm dx \ne 0$.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the answer. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as correct. By the way, is there any general method for proving the closure under multiplication of a set of orthogonal functions (if they are)?

Comment: Why the "group-theory" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Using Legendre polynomials,
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} P_1(x)P_2(x)P_3(x)\,dx = \frac{6}{35} \neq 0. $$